# Django не подключается в PostreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql

Такой вопрос, у меня при попытке подключения Сервера Django к PostreSQL Db уже существующей вылезает ошибка
" port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? "
Файрволл также отключен

ОС Windows 10

В настройках прописал всё правильно, пароль убрал специально, так он там есть:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'ps_store_db',
        'USER': 'zesshi',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5433',
    }
}
```

Уже менял порт подлкючения с 5432 на 5433 всё равно выходит ошибка
Вносить какие либо изменения в PgAdmin в своей дб я могу, так что не могу понять в чем ошибка и почему он наотрез не хочет соединятсья

Также проверил соединение через программу DBeaver, соединение есть [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А сервер PostgreSql точно слушает этот порт?  *netstat -a* показывает что порт открыт и его слушают? И что за опреационная система? Если Линукс и стоит SELinux то вероятней всего надо дать разрешение процессу Django на подключение к порту 5432

Comment: Я там немного перепутал,в данный момент стоит порт 5433, уже исправил в основном тексте
ОС Стоит Windows 10

Comment: Проверил через netstat слушает такой адрес:   TCP    0.0.0.0:5433           DESKTOP-3Q9ML7C:0      LISTENING
Именно 127.0.0.1:5433 такого порта вообще нет в сводке

Answer (score -1):

Для работы с PostgreSql не достаточно просто прописать в настройках setings.py соединение с базой данных. Необходимо установить драйвер для работы с БД psycopg2.

Comment: Psycopg2 уже установлен, он бы не дал в принципе прописать команду запуска сервера, тут проблема именно в соединении